# Regex for specific file structure

Tags: regex, perl

I need to parse file with next simple structure:

```
some string 1
some string 2
some string 3

some string x
some string y
some string z
...
```

File consist of 2 parts separated by "\n\n" or "\r\n\r\n". This separator present in my example after "some string 3". Each part is optional, that is if first part omitted than there will be 1(but with my regex I need 2 empty lines) empty line(\n|\r\n) before second part. And if second part is omitted than there will be any number of empty lines after first part(include no empty lines at all).

I'm trying to achieve desired result with regex like this:

```
(?isx: \h* (.+)? \h* (?:(?:\n|\r\n){2,} \h* (.+))? \s*)
```

But with no success because first "(.+)?" very greedy and if I making 2nd part non-optional it violates my requirements that both part must be optional. I know that I can use split /(?:\n|\r\n)/, $str in this case but this file in future could have more complex structure so I can't use split.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually might want to use a non-greedy group, since you don't want to match your seperator.

```
(?ìsx: (?:
       (.*?)          # Non greedy
       (?:\r?\n){2,}  # also matches \r\n\n but that might not be of concern
       |\r?\n)        # one empty line.
       (.*)           # second group
)
```

I don't know what you wanted to achieve with the `\h`s. If you want to ensure that there is something in the lines (right now, the `.` also could all match `\n` or spaces) you could try something like `(?:[^\n]+\n)*?` for the groups.

Also, for brevities sake, I avoided the explicit `?` you used. There might be a difference in results. If you match nothing under a star, you'll get the empty string, if you don't match at all, the value of the group-variable is `undefined`. Here is a short example to show the difference:

```
"aa" =~ /(c)?(d*)aa/
```

Here `$1` is `undefined`, while `$2` is the empty string. This minor difference might yield some annoying warnings or unexpected results if someone tested with `defined` for the contents of a group.

Comment: Absolutely what I needed. I tried to catch redundant space characters with \h s but now realized that this is almost useless.